# Updating django ManytoMany relationship with rest framwork modelserializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

## Updating django ManytoMany relationship with rest framwork modelserializer

I am using django and just getting started with API's through the rest framework. I am using the built in  Model and viewserializer for a profile model. The profile model has "following" attripute which keeps track of the profiles followers as a manytomany relationship with other profiles. Through my API I am trying to add a profile when a the this queryset when the followbutton is pressed however the Patched request through the API instead replaces the whole following set instead of simply appending it. I basically want the API to use the "add" method for m2m in django. Any tips?

```
## models.py ##

class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    following = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True, null = True, symmetrical=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

### serialisers.py

```
`class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'following')

## views.py

class ProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

`
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('profiles', views.ProfileView)

```
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path('following', views.following, name = 'following'),
    path('profile/<str:username>', views.profile, name = 'profile'),


    #API

    path('api/', include(router.urls))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the save method and do something like this:

```
profile.following.add(Profile.objects.get(id=id))
```